# Perform actions within a time frame in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I'm trying to do a standby mode in PHP.
In the rows of my SQL Table I'm saving a time, 'sleep' and 'wakeup' which contains an hour. Example:

```
| id |   sleep  |  wakeup  |
----------------------------
| 1  | 21:00:00 | 07:00:00 |
| 2  | 19:00:00 | 09:30:00 |
| 3  | 08:15:00 | 18:00:00 |
```

Each row has an IP address saved.
To explain better, I have 22 raspberry pi in kiosk mode, and 22 screens.
Each raspberry has an assigned an IP, and it's checking with JavaScript if the actual hour is inside the standby time frame.

How can I program this?

Thanks.

Comment: **Note:** The client and server time can be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup a cron which is running every x minutes. 
In this cron you can check if it's time for you raspberry to wake up or to sleep

Comment: I think they want to use JavaScript somehow from how the question reads.

Comment: I think you can setup a NodeJS cron, but you'll have to check every x minutes if it's time for them to wake up or to sleep. I don't think you can setup in SQL an event which trigger a function

Comment: a cron is just a file (it might be a PHP script) that you setup to run every x minutes. But if you're talking about an event triggered when it's time. I don't think so